# Implementing a built in GUI with pymunk and pygame in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, pymunk

I am looking to make a python program in which I can have a sidebar GUI along with an interactive 2d pymunk workspace to the right of it, which is to be docked within the same frame.

Does anyone know how I might implement this?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You have to actually try something, then come back with your code in a minimum reproducible example. StackOverflow is not the place for "where do I start?" type questions.

Comment: Hi DetectivePikachu, I appreciate the reply, I totally agree, but I was looking more for what kind of Python modules people would recommend for me to be able to do this, not how to code it. I'm asking where to start because I can't seem to find anything online. At the moment, I'm not even entirely sure if it is possible. I will do some more research. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use pygame as your display. If an object is chosen, you can add it to the pymunk space at the same time as using pymunk to get each body's space and draw it onto the display. This is how I've written my games.